# Does this graph imply a violation of homoscedasticity?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, heteroscedasticity

I assume that this graph doesn't support the assumption of homoscedasticity. Am I right? Does it make sense to carry out another test to be sure?

y-axis: Regression Standardized Residual, x-axis: Regression Standardized Predicted Value, dependent variable: Score of a questionnaire measuring rage attacks, n=156

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. For those of us who don't speak German (I think it's German) could you translate the axis label? I think I understand most of it, but not "geschatzer Wert" and "think I understand" is not really good.

Comment: Sure, it's in my text: y-axis: Regression Standardized Residual, x-axis: Regression Standardized Predicted Value.

Comment: You should have a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breusch%E2%80%93Pagan_test)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chart indicates homoscedasticity but Breusch-Pagan test p<.001](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/437971/chart-indicates-homoscedasticity-but-breusch-pagan-test-p-001)

Comment: There is a presumably a  constraint on the response, say no score is lower than zero. Hence, residuals must plot above some line that in spirit is residual = minimum observed $-$  fitted. (Standardization affects details only.) This alone inhibits or prohibits homoscedasticity. If there is an upper bound only, all the more reason to consider a generalized linear model with appropriate link rather than plain regression. For more, see the thread suggested just above as duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for your help! 
Breusch-Pagan-test shows a significance of 0.187, the modified Breusch-Pagan p= 0.242 and the White-test p= 0.587. 
So, can I assume homoscedasticity?
But the problem which Nick Cox wrote about stays...so is it still advisable to run a generalized linear model instead of a multiple linear regression?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate because in the question marked as a potential duplicate the N was much larger and the Breusch Pagan test was statistically significant.

Answer (score 1):

##### You have bigger problems than heteroskedasticity here

Based on the straight diagonal line forming the lower bound of the residuals on the lower-left side of the plot, it appears that you are using a linear regression to deal with a non-negative response variable (possibly a count variable?).  If this is the case then it would be usual to either use a count regression model or at least use a logarithmic transformation on your response variable in the model.  This would usually give you a more appropriate model for this kind of data and would typically deal with the heteroskedasticity at issue.

Before worrying about heteroskedasticity, I recommend that you reconsider whether you are using the correct model.  If your response is a count variable then I would recommend starting with a negative-binomial count regression.  If your response is not a count variable, but is some other non-negative variable, I would recommend that you consider a log-linear regression (with an adjustment for response values of zero).  You can also consider variations on these models, but that is where I would start.

Comment: One thing I would like to add: the original poster DID look at the residuals plot, and decided that this is not how it should look. That is a good thing; I have seen many people not looking at it or ignoring it.

Answer (score 0):

Two essential assumptions of regression are being unbiased and variance independence with observations. Mathematically, $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is:

$$
\varepsilon  \sim \mathcal{N} (0, \sigma^{2} I_{n}).
$$

In your case, it seems that the estimated variance increase with observations. Two possibilities : the first one is a problem of heteroscedasticity and maybe a problem of sampling.

I hope it helps.

Comment: $\varepsilon \sim \mathcal N(0,sigma^2 I_n)$ is *much* stronger than being "unbiased" (this is not the usual terminology though, I'm guessing what you mean is that the errors are mean 0 conditional on regressors) and "variance independence with observations" (the usual terminology here should be "homoskedastic". Also, the answer is vague: what does it mean for those two assumptions to be "essential". For example, if the only issue is heteroskedasticity, OLS is still consistent (although conventional standard errors may be misleading).